# Converting to UTC is giving NaN error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, utc

I have below code which is giving `NaN` error when i am trying to convert it into `Date.UTC` format.

```
 let sDate = "2019, 10, 19";
 let min = Date.UTC(sDate);
```

whereas below code is giving me correct result

```
let min = Date.UTC(2019, 10, 19);
```

but as per my need, `sDate` is supposed to be passed as parameter because it may vary. How to correct this?

Comment: *"it may vary":* the string formats that `Date` can parse are limited, and in some cases engine-dependent. So, what exactly are the input formats you need to support? Can you be complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC), `Date.UTC` does not take date string as an argument. It takes individual parts.

> **Date.UTC(year[, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, millisecond]]]]]])**

So when you pass `Date.UTC('2019, 10, 19')`, you are just passing year's value and not other values. Year's value is also not number. Hence NaN.

If you wish to create UTC date using date string, you will have to split values.

---

The date *arguments* are **not a string**:

```js
let sDate = "2019, 10, 19";
 let min = Date.UTC(...sDate.split(', '));
 console.log(new Date(min));
```

Comment: @trincot month january corresponds to 0 so 10 is november, checkout the docs of the method before commenting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini 10 should be Oct. as you are creating date from string. Ideally, date in user readable format should be considered as normal date and not as date in JS. Hence, month should be subtracted 1 from it

Comment: Yes, but I would be surprised if the *string* "2019, 10, 19" is intending to point to November, and not October. That would *really* be a very confusing string format.

Comment: the OP question was about passing parameters AS in string, compliant to `Date.UTC()` docs. There is no requirement to make it readable **without** reading the docs.

Comment: Also look at the example, with the same parameter is required the **same output**. Additional considerations are out of scope.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini I took the liberty to update your answer with an explanation. Please revert if not required or add/ correct any incorrect value

Comment: "*Date.UTC does not take date string as an argument*" is incorrect. It takes from one to seven arguments which can all be of any type, including string, that when evaluated and passed to *ToNumber* result in a suitable value. `Date.UTC('2019',false, true, [5])` is valid for 2019-01-01T05:00:00Z.

Comment: @RobG you are right, the assertion was too broad. Feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.split (with destructuring) to convert a *known* date string format into year, month, day. You have do subtract 1 from the month value when passing to the Date.UTC function since this accepts a month value from 0 to 11 (January to December).

If you want to do more sophisticated Date parsing I strongly recommend you use a library such as [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). This is well tested and has a very flexible API.

```js
const sDate = "2019, 10, 19";
const [year, month, day] = sDate.split(",");
console.log("Date components:", {year, month, day});
// Date constructor takes a month from 0: January to 11: December
const utcDate = Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day);
console.log("Date (ISO):", new Date(utcDate).toISOString());
console.log("Date (toLocaleString):", new Date(utcDate).toLocaleString("en", { timeZone: "UTC"}));
```

Comment: `.map(number)` is redundant, [*Date.UTC*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-date.utc) calls *ToNumber* on each of the arguments anyway. ;-)

Comment: Good call @RobG, I just ran Number on the inputs to be explicit about it, but you're right it's not necessary!

Answer (score -1):

The Date.UTC() method accepts parameters similar to the Date constructor but treats them as UTC

```
Date.UTC(year[, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, millisecond]]]]]])
```

you can't use string directly

```js
getData=(d)=>{
            return [d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate(), d.getHours(),d.getMinutes()];
        };
        
        
        let splited = getData(new Date('2019, 10, 19'))
        
        console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(...splited)));
```